# Cannot reindex Catalog URL Rewrites in magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, php

Went to 
`system->index management` , 
checked on (Catalog URL Rewrites),when i clicked on submit to Reindex Data , i get an error message

Cannot initialize the indexer process.

I also tried to reindex data using terminal with the command

`sudo php shell/indexer.php --reindexall`

got error

```
Catalog URL Rewrites index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1139 Got error 'this version of PCRE is compiled without UTF support at offset 0' from regexp' in /respective-installaton-location/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
```

also tried

`sudo php -f ./shell/indexer.php -- -reindex catalog_url`

got same error message

```
Catalog URL Rewrites index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1139 Got error 'this version of PCRE is compiled without UTF support at offset 0' from regexp' in /respective-installaton-location/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
```

Please suggest what should be done, Any help would be appreciated.
I need to reindex catalog url as i made some changes in
`system->configuration->catalog->Search engine optimisation->Use Categories Path for Product URLs`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a **wrong** `pcre lib` installed, try to recompile PCRE in `utf8`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37118500/6408849) answer

Comment: sorry , it did not wok in my case ..